# Z3 Theorem Prover log file documentation?

Tags: z3, smt

As of recent, I am working with Axiom Profiler, which parses Z3 log files for information.
But the program has encountered problems when parsing lines that don't start with a header (a square bracket).
These lines occur after an [assign] line in the log file.

```
  [assign] (not #6339) clause (not p3) p2
    (not (= z3.sk.3 -26::Int)) 
    (= z3.sk.3 -39::Int)
```

Unfortunatly I did not find any documentation of this.
Is this a new change to Z3's log file? and where can I find the documentation to what this entails?

The log file I used is generated by using:

```
z3 trace=true proof=true trace-file-name=foo.log ./input.smt2
```

Any help is appreicated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think there's any documentation on the format of the log files. Your best bet is to look at the source-code of z3 itself, and reverse-engineer from there.

Comment: Please submit a new issue for this at https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues . The log file format may have changed recently as there is ongoing work on a new SMT core that may well have changed that, but I can't tell for sure.